# Radio Button check issue using knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Iam running foreach loop above the radio button but unfortunately i could not check any of radio button.Here is my view

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="form-section">Qualification Factor</h3>
                <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: leadqualificlist">
                    //Here is my foreach loop
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="radio-list radio-list-padding">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="serious" value="0" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk, attr: { name: 'grp' + $data.Negativescore}" />
                                    Negative
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Iam having list in leadqualificlist observable array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio buttons behave differently than checkboxes, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked **if and only if** the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute or the value specified by the checkedValue parameter. <...> When the user changes which radio button is selected, KO will set your model property to equal the value of the selected radio button.

So, having that said, you cannot set different names for your checkboxex (using attr binding), but should set value in binding, like this:

```
...
<input type="radio" name="serious" data-bind="value: Scoreschk, checked:$parent.selectedScoreCheck" />
...
```

Now your view model should look like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.leadqualificlist = ko.observableArray([new Qualification(0, 5),
                                          new Qualification(1, 2),
                                          new Qualification(2, 1)]);
    self.selectedScoreCheck = ko.observable("2"); // Note here must be string!
}
```

Where Qualification is:

```
function Qualification(scoreCheck, negativeScore) {
    this.Scoreschk = scoreCheck;
    this.Negativescore = negativeScore;
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w8y3ax7h/).

Comment: So update it accordingly. What exactly doesn't work? Are there errors in console?

Comment: At the time of page load radio-button is in disable state, according to my requirement it should not be disable state.

Comment: What is the value of the radio observable (selectedScoreCheck in my sample)? Does it equals to the value of your desired ratio-button? You can update my fiddle according to your project, so I could see the problem

Comment: If i remove foreach its working fine but if i keep foreach radio button is getting disable.And i am using bootstrap css.And this scenario will work fine in fiddle but not in local machine.

Comment: @user3483538, well then issue is somewhere else. Try checking console for errors. Since current jsfiddle works for your provided code, can you accept the answer?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin An excellent demonstration that helped me understand the issue I had with checked radio buttons. I know that stackOverflow doesn't want plain 'thanks' comments, but thank you as well as the OP :)